# How to rename Button with Edittext Value in one activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android.

I want to give value from a edittext and set it to a button text.
I Can do that when edittext and button are in separate activities (with intents and putting extras), but what about when they are in same activity?

here is the code that I so far got (I'm using dialog for getting edittext value and the edittext is in "addalbumsdialog" layout):

```
public class Albums extends Activity {
Button b1;
EditText et1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.album);

    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addalbum);

    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startDialog();
        }
    });
}

protected void startDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    myAlertDialog.setTitle("Name?");
    myAlertDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.addalbumsdialog, null));
    myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.album1);
            b1.setText(et1.getText().toString());
            b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
    myAlertDialog.show();
}

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: SO whats wrong with your code.??Where you are stuck?

Comment: you can do the same without starting a new Activity.

Comment: @kaylan pvs: It's not working and I give "Force close" error when I click OK in Dialog.

Comment: you will get force close as you are not findViewById by your dialog's view. You Just have to set inflater.inflate(R.layout.addalbumsdialog, null) before findViewById of button b1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
 View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.addalbumsdialog, null);
 myAlertDialog.setView(view);       
 et1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 myAlertDialog.setTitle("Name?");
```

Declare Button as a instance variable

```
Button b2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.album);
b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addalbum);
```

Then on Button click

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        b2.setText(et1.getText().toString();

    }
});
```

If Button b1 belongs to the view inflated and you need to setText to it

Then

```
protected void startDialog() {
AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.addalbumsdialog, null);
myAlertDialog.setView(view);       
et1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.album1);
myAlertDialog.setTitle("Name?");
myAlertDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.addalbumsdialog, null));
myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b1.setText(et1.getText().toString());

    }
});
myAlertDialog.show();
}
```

You haven't mentioned which button text you want to change. So posted both

Answer (score 1):

You should replace this

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
  et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  myAlertDialog.setTitle("Name?");
  myAlertDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.addalbumsdialog, null));
```

With

```
View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.addalbumsdialog, null);
myAlertDialog.setView(view);       
et1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.album1);
myAlertDialog.setTitle("Name?");
```

And add create `Button b2` as instance variable like:

```
Button b2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.album);
b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addalbum);
```

And then on Button click

```
@Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    b2.setText(et1.getText().toString();

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the code like this

```
public class Albums extends Activity {
    Button b1;
    EditText et1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.album);

        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addalbum);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.album1);

        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void startDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        myAlertDialog.setTitle("Name?");
        myAlertDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.addalbumsdialog, null));
        myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {           
                b1.setText(et1.getText().toString());


            }
        });
        myAlertDialog.show();
    }

    }
```